# normal distribution in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I want to use `rnorm(n, mean, sd)`.  I can understand that the n is the number of observations with mean and sd. But please tell me in simple words what the results after running `rnorm(n,mean,sd)` are!

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you don't understand.  It is n observations from the distribution with the given mean and sd as you stated.

Comment: For example:   
 rnorm(10,500,80)
 [1] 502.0629 548.9628 549.4252 473.6572 548.6160 437.7743 515.5681 452.3997
 [9] 471.2482 351.4196

These numbers what they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you run the following:

> rnorm(5, 10, 2)

What you get is the value of five points randomly drawn from a normal distribution that has a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 2.

It's a random draw, so each time you rerun this line you will get a different set of numbers. They all belong to the same normal distribution, though.

(If you want to obtain the same set of values every time you run the command you need to use `set.seed()` first)

Answer (score 1):

The function call results in n observations sampled from a normal distribution that fits your parameters for mean and standard deviation. That is, if you were to sample a large amount of observations, say 1,000,000, then the mean of your observations would approximate your `mean` and the standard deviation (a measure of how "spread out" or how much your data "varies") would similarly approximate your `sd`. The larger your `n` the closer your calculations should approximate the `mean` and `sd` parameters.

Below a quick example

> obs<-rnorm(n=1e6, mean=0, sd=1) # a standard normal distribution
>   mean(obs)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEtkq.png) 0.001220156
>   sd(obs)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEtkq.png) 0.9993028

A quick histogram will show you that the sampling approximates the standard normal distribution

> hist(obs)
>   [image]
>   You can also see that the mean/sd get closer to the parameters if you increase the size of your `n`.

```
> obs<-rnorm(n=1e6, mean=0, sd=1) # a standard normal distribution
> sizes<-10^c(1,2,3,4,5,6) #various sample sizes
> comp<-sapply(sizes, function(x){
+ obs<-rnorm(n=x,mean=0,sd=1)
+ c(mean=mean(obs), sd=sd(obs))})
> comp
          [,1]         [,2]        [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
mean 0.5067287 -0.007100886 -0.02529011 -0.005051383 -0.001862262 0.0007186828
sd   1.2146560  1.005648941  0.99851624  0.989914551  1.002872287 1.0006376314
```